# Classroom google update answer

Tags: python, google-api, google-classroom

I want to update answer value but I get http error.
I can update only 2 fields with grades or not?
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the response of your request, the `updateMask` may only contain `draftGrade` or `assignedGrade`. Incorrect value on updateMask will result to error code 400.

### Update:

I tried creating courseWork and 2 dummy student that will submit answer on a multiple choice question. Upon submitting 2 answers, I tried updating the `multipleChoiceSubmission` by using `courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.patch` and the value didn't change. There are several fields you can update using patch method. See [StudentSubmissions](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#StudentSubmission)

### Further Reading:

- [MultipleChoiceSubmission](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#multiplechoicesubmission)
- [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.patch](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch)

Comment: Is it at all possible to pass the multiple answer value from the server to the google class? 
because updateMask specifies fields for updates (Mask that identifies which fields on the student submission to update. This field is required to do an update. The update fails if invalid fields are specified.)

Comment: @ДенисНичипорчик - I tried it and confirming that you cannot update the value of multipleChoiceSubmission value.  There are limited fields that you can update using patch method. I provided a link in my updated answer above.